# Did Firefox (v 39.0) drop support for "Global Menu"?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, globalmenu

... and if so, how to fix / re-enable support? Or would this be fixed by subsequent point releases of Firefox?

Comment: "Global Menu"? Sorry, I am slightly confused what you mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot resolved the issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the menu bar on top?

Right click on the hamburger (three stripes) on the upper right corner and click on menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

It just works: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> still brings up the File menu, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> still brings up the Help menu, moving the mouse to the panel still brings up the full menu as well …

Running FireFox 39.0 on Ubuntu 14.4.02 Unity 7.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to open the menu bar and <kbd>Alt</kbd> again to close.

---

```
% apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 39.0+build5-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
```